Is there a way to auto-link to products when writing a post?
I have created a post where I list items in my product catalogue and add links to said products.
Currently, I manually add links to the products once I have typed them out.
However, I want to know if there is a way to search for and create a link on the fly to a product in my catalogue (where the product exists).
Much in the same way that referring to a user by typing @ brings up a list which filters as you type, I imagine that a (different) trigger character (such as a colon :) might be used in this case.
For example, whilst listing products, I might want to link to Product 1234, so I might type :product_12 and it suggests the closest matches as I type.
Is this possible?  Is it a feature that I can build myself?
(Note: I am new to WordPress (and to this SE site too) so have added the tags I think might be relevant but please change accordingly if not.)
Thank you.

If you type  [[ in the editor then you get latest posts link inserter, but it seems to be only for post and page types.

What about ctrl+k in the editor to activate the link search?

@birgire Would you believe it - both solutions work! Now I face the dilemma of which to use as the decision process will no doubt cripple me but that's no longer your problem. Thank you! Please combine both suggestions into a single answer so that I can accept. Thanks again!

Mus, great to hear that, I posted it as an answer.

Thank you. Also, typing [[ does in fact bring up (suggest) items in my products catalogue, which turn into links upon selection. (You may want to adjust your answer to this effect.) thanks again!

Thanks for update, I did update it

We can type ctrl+k in the editor to activate the link search:

that will search in all public post types.
We can also type [[ in the editor to get the link inserter for latest posts.
